# C++ Program with clasess

Tags: c++, oop, inner-classes

I'm trying to make a program and while I'm making it I'm learning classes, inheritance and things I'll need. I'll give you the condition of the program and the code to where I got to.

The 2nd class I made it inherit the 1st, but I can't get the console to return the student's grade. Тhe condition they gave me confuses me and I can't figure out how they want to calculate the student's grade? Thanks in advance for your time and kindness :)

**I. Define a student class CStudent storing name information,
student's faculty number and major to provide:**

1. Create objects using a copy constructor
2. Creation of objects by explicit constructor (with parameters)
3. Using an implicit constructor
4. Assignment operator =
5. Comparison operator ==
6. Comparison operator < (by faculty number)
7. To read student data from stream input - operator>>
8. To output the student data to stream output - operator<<
9. Establish the member variables (mutators)
10. Reading the member variables (accessors)

**II. Define a student booklet class CStudBook that inherits
CStudent with a member data container of the student's grades. To implement
a constructor with a filename parameter from which to initialize
container and the following methods:**

1. Create an object using another object (copy constructor)
2. Creating an object using explicit parameters
3. Creating an object by default constructor
4. Calculate and return the student's grade point average
5. operator>>
6. operator<<
7. Print

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string> 
#include <vector> 
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class CStudent {
public:
    // Default constructor
    CStudent() = default;

    // Explicit constructor
    CStudent(string name, int facnum, string specialty) {
        this->name = name;
        this->facnum = facnum;
        this->specialty = specialty;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    CStudent(const CStudent& obj) {
        this->name = obj.name;
        this->facnum = obj.facnum;
        this->specialty = obj.specialty;
    }

    // Method, that prints the contents of the object
    void PrintStudent() const {
        cout << "Name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Fac. num: " << facnum << endl;
        cout << "Specialty: " << specialty << endl;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& out, const CStudent& obj) // output operator
    {
        out << "Name:" << obj.name << "-> FacNumber: " << obj.facnum << std::endl;

    }

  

    bool operator <(const CStudent& obj) // operator for comparison of two objects
    {
        return name < obj.name;
        return facnum < obj.facnum;
        
    }

    // operator login should be added here



    private:
    string name;
    int facnum;
    string specialty;
};

class CStudBook : public CStudent {
private:
    int grade;







};











// Function, that gets student data from the console
// and creates an instance of the CStudent class using this data
CStudent CreateFromConsole() {
    cout << "Enter name: ";
    string name;
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Enter fac. num: ";
    int facnum;
    cin >> facnum;

    cout << "Enter specialty: ";
    string specialty;
    cin >> specialty;

    cout << "Enter student grade: ";
    int grade;
    cin >> grade;
    


    cout << endl;
    return CStudent(name, facnum, specialty); // returns an instance of the class
}





int main() {
    vector<CStudent> students; // stack-like container

    cout << "Enter total number of students: ";
    int count;
    cin >> count;

    cout << "Enter details of students" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // Create an instance of the class
        CStudent student = CreateFromConsole();

        // Push a copy of the object into the container
        students.push_back(student);




    }

    cout << endl;

    cout << "Details" << endl << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
        students[i].PrintStudent();
        cout << endl;
    }

    fflush(stdin); // Reset input console 
    getchar(); // Pause
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That `operator<` is terrible.

Comment: The task says: `Define a student booklet class CStudBook ... with a member data container of the student's grades.` and `Calculate and return the student's grade point average` so they expect you to store multiple grades for a student in `CStudBook` and to calculate an average. You can use `std::vector<int>` or something to store the grades or maybe `std::map`/`std::multimap` if the grades are needed be to associated with class (this does not seem to be in the task)

Comment: Okay , but as Retired Ninja said my operator are bad. Need some explanation or someone to rework it and see how its done. I couldn't find similar task like mine to see how its done properly and clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I think `grade` is private members of `class CStudBook` so you can't call it from `class CStudent`.

If you want to access it my suggested keyword for you to find is **protected members**

Comment: any solution can you write down? and explain in code?

Comment: You just need to change `private`  in  `class CStudBook`  to  `protected`